# The best approach to deploying a python solution to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, python

I have a Python solution that is deployed to AWS, my current deployment approach feels very archaic. I follow these steps each time I update the service:

1. tar the python files that have changed
2. scp the tar into the /tmp directory on the instance
3. run sudo python setup.py install on the setup.py of the new files
4. restart supervisord

Multiple versions of the server never exist, if there is a non-backward compatible change there is a force update mechanism on the clients.

How could I improve this process using the newest technologies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using an orchestration tool like [Ansible](http://www.ansible.com/home). Start with free open source version. You can also try [SaltStack](http://saltstack.com/), Chef or Puppet but Ansible is in my opinion the simplest of them and it does not require a server component. And since it is based on python it should be right up your alley.

And for mission critical deployment I would suggest [blue-green](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/BlueGreenDeployment.html) strategy.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution might be: [AWS Elastic Beanstalk](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/).

AWS Elastic Beanstalk support many platforms, including Python. Currently, for Python, they support:

- 64bit Amazon Linux 2015.03 v1.4.3 running Python 3.4
- 64bit Amazon Linux 2015.03 v1.4.3 running Python 2.7
- 64bit Amazon Linux 2015.03 v1.4.3 running Python 2.6
- 64bit Debian jessie v1.4.3 running Python 3.4 (Preconfigured - Docker)

If the above environment is not suitable for you, you can also configure your own environment via Docker. See the full of environment in [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts.platforms.html).

AWS Elastic Beanstalk handle many things:

- Auto Scaling Group
- Load Balancer
- Application versioning
- Notification
- Custom resources (e.g: RDS, ElastiCache, etc.)

You can also extend your environment using `.ebextensions` script. For example, you want configure SSL or add additional EBS volume.

It also support Blue-Green deployment strategy by [swapping CNAME](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.CNAMESwap.html).